# How to concatenate a string into activeTextArea in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

This is a possible duplicate. However, I can't seem to find a solution here on Stackoverflow.

I have been trying to concatenate a singe string, namely "Clone", to a textAre in yii. However, so far I have not been able to implement it correctly. Following is my textArea.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class ="col-md-4">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'tag'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'tag', array('rows'=>1, 'cols'=>20,'class'=>'resize-non form-control', 'id'=>'newTags')); ?>
      </div>
</div>
```

But when I try to concatenate it like the following code, I get an error.

```
<?php echo $form->textArea($model,'tag'.''.'Clone', array('rows'=>1, 'cols'=>20,'class'=>'resize-non form-control', 'id'=>'newTags')); ?>
```

Error: Property "Dashboard.titleClone" is not defined.

I have also tried to get it using a variable like the following:

```
<?php $clone = $model->title.''.'Clone' ?>
<?php echo $form->textArea($model,$clone, array('rows'=>1, 'cols'=>20,'class'=>'resize-non form-control', 'id'=>'newTags')); ?>
```

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. I had no clue you cold do this, but it somehow makes sense.

You can add a string to an attribute of the model by concatenating it before you use it in the activeTextArea like the following:

```
<?php $model->tag .= "Clone"; ?>

<div class="row">
      <div class ="col-md-4">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'tag'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'tag', array('rows'=>1, 'cols'=>20,'class'=>'resize-non form-control', 'id'=>'newTags')); ?>
      </div>
</div>
```